# hotkey to button in C# Windows application

Tags: c#

How do i make a hotkey to button in C# Windows application

Answer (score 24):

Override Form's `ProcessCmdKey`.  If you find a keystroke that you like, call the same method that the button would.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.X))
    {
        DoSomething();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi!");
}
```

**EDIT**: Jay's method is better if you can find an appropriate mnemonic.

Answer (score 20):

Set the button's UseMnemonic property to true and add an ampersand (&) just before the letter in the button's Text property you want to use for the hotkey.

The user would press Alt +  to activate the hotkey.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! =^,^=

Answer (score 16):

Windows Application and shortcut key are synonyms. People prefer to use shortcut keys for faster activity. Assume you are in a text box and you want to hit F5 to reload the form. You do not want to move your mouse cursor. So, what you will be doing is that you will be adding “Key Down” event to the text box. But, if you are in a different text box or in a button, that will not work. So, you will add “Key Down” event to your form.

But you need to enable a property to work it properly and that’s the trick.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
    {
        btnRefresh_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

But golden trick is, in the property window of the Form make the following changes:

```
KeyPreview = True
```

Enjoy programming.

Comment: How to trap it in UserControl?

Comment: You are a saviour!

Comment: I had to add this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown); to my InitializeComponent() code in the form designer to link my function to the form's events.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //Do whatever you want here...
        }
    }
```

Of course you can change `Keys.Enter` to whatever key you want.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are AcceptButton and CancelButton properties in every form. If you're going to narrow your hotkey usage to enter and escape buttons, which are, in turn, should invoke certain buttons, I'd recommend you to consider the usage of these properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
 if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.W) 
   { 
     //do something 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

even though this post is super old here is a simpler way to do it , the code is pretty poor but it gets the job done very nicely.

```
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

            button1.PerformClick();

        }
```

Comment: I don't think it gets the job done because this won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Micheal's answer here's a more elegant version if you won't use combined keys:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch(keyData)
    {
         case Keys.F2:
             // do something...
             return true;
         case Keys.F3:
             // do something...
             return true;
         case Keys.F4:
             // do something...
             return true;
         default:
             return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }            
}
```