# Shortcut Keys for Saving or Editing Record in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows form application where i have some textboxes values and two buttons, one is **SAVE** and the other is **EDIT**. The buttons code for saving record upon **CLICK** is working very fine. But now i want to add the **keyboard shortcut** keys to SAVE and EDIT record by **pressing CTRL+S for SAVE** and **CTRL+E for EDIT**. Please help me with this. I am very new to this programming field so please be **precise** and **very clear** where to write my code in the program.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474397/hotkey-to-button-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should set the `Form.KeyPreview` property of your `Form` to `true`.
Cause `Form.KeyPreview` property([as MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key
>   events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

Then it is necessary to create an event handler for `KeyDown` event of the `Form`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
   {
        buttonSave_Click(null, null);                
   }
   if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
   {
        buttonEdit_Click(null, null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MenuStrip` to your form. Add two `ToolStripMenuItem` Save and Edit, attach them your EventHandler button clicks. Assign the desired values (Ctrl+S, Ctrl+E) to the `ShortcutKeys` property.

If your application does not require main menu then you can hide it (`Visible` = false).

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to override ProcessDialogKey() for your Form.

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        Keys key = keyData & Keys.KeyCode;
        bool contrloIsPressed = (keyData & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control ? true : false;

        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.S:
                if (contrloIsPressed)
                    Save();
                break;
            case Keys.E:
                if (contrloIsPressed)
                    Edit();
                break;
        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this for help you.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Q | Keys.Control:
                    Close();

                    return false;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message message, Keys keys)
{
            switch (keys)
            {
                case Keys.A | Keys.Control:
                    // ... Process Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B ...
                    adding = true;
                    updating = false;
                    EnableText();
                    ClearText();
                    AutoNo();
                    return true; // signal that we've processed this key
                case Keys.S | Keys.Control:
                    // ... Process Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B ...
                    SaveUpdate();
                    return true; // signal that we've processed this key
                case Keys.E | Keys.Control:
                    // ... Process Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B ...
                    updating = true;
                    adding = false;
                    EnableText();
                    return true; // signal that we've processed this key
                case Keys.D | Keys.Control:
                    // ... Process Shift+Ctrl+Alt+B ...
                    DeleteRecord();
                    return true; // signal that we've processed this key
            }
            // run base implementation
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref message, keys);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer add any extra value that the previous answers did not already provide?